# Не запускается kdiff3 из tortoisehg

Tags: mercurial

На маке поставил *tortoisehg*, затем скачал, добавил в папку программы *kdiff3* (почему-то не шел в комплекте первого). `kdiff3` не запускается из tool reserve в tortoisehg. не могу разобраться. Прописал следующие строки для tortoisehg по рекомендации в инете

```
[extdiff]

cmd.kdiff3 = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3

[merge-tools]
kdiff3.args = $base $local $other -o $output# Generated by TortoiseHg settings dialog
```

не работает.

Comment: кажется разобрался

Comment: Пожалуйста, по возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.